# Why are sonarqube runners giving me different number of violation errors?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, sonarqube, sonar-runner

I tried running my code analysis against different sonnar runners:

- with ANT I tried:

  - sonar-ant-task-2.2.jar
  - sonar-ant-task-2.0.jar
- with maven I tried:

  - sonarqube-eclipse plugin
  - sonar:sonar maven task

Why are they giving me different violations count even though they all use the same quality profile?

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here given the few information available (please share the configuration of your analysis) but it can be due to the fact that bytecode is not provided when running with ant whereas this is done automatically when running with maven.

Comment: i can focus the question on just maven part in that case... Why is it that I get different results with maven task and sonarqube eclipse plugin?

Comment: For this difference, I guess that some checks are not run in incremental mode (eclipse analysis) (coverage for instance is not analyzed) and you get different results. Once again it is _very_ hard to give you an answer with sparse information.

Comment: theres not too much to share... My eclipse plugin i run without any configuration (additional to setting up remote server that is) and maven one is run with (sonar.host.url, sonar.dryrun set to true and sonar.language set to java).

analysis is by default set to analysis mode (not incremental). I don't even think eclipse plugin supports incremental mode. If you need any more information, please let me know

Comment: For instance, what are the issues that differs (share rule keys) ?

Comment: I've detected one in specific: Performance - Method concatenates strings using + in a loop

with maven task i get two violations. with eclipse plugin, there's only one.